# ORA-01008 but all variables are bound and working in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

```
Command.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(REQHOURS), SUM(REQQUANTITY) / COUNT(*) 
    FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDERNUMBER = :OrderNumber AND 
    OPERATION = (SELECT MIN(OPERATION) FROM ORDERS 
    WHERE ORDERNUMBER = :OrderNumber AND OPERATION > :Operation)";
Command.Parameters.Add("OrderNumber", order.OrderNumber);
Command.Parameters.Add("Operation", order.Operation);
```

The query above is working fine in the Oracle SQL Developer (OSQLD for further reference) application but when I run it in C# I get the following error:

> ORA-01008: not all variables bound

When I debugged parts of the query in C# I found out that if I remove `AND OPERATION > :Operation` the query executes but the `DataReader` is `Null`. If I than run it in OSQLD I do get values back.

For people wondering, `order.OrderNumber` and `order.Operation` are certainly not `Null`.

I have multiple queries in my application and all of them work fine. It's only this one that gives me problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after some thinking basically...

The code I started with was as follow:

```
Command.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(REQHOURS), SUM(REQQUANTITY) / COUNT(*) 
    FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDERNUMBER = :OrderNumber AND 
    OPERATION = (SELECT MIN(OPERATION) FROM ORDERS 
    WHERE ORDERNUMBER = :OrderNumber AND OPERATION > :Operation)";
Command.Parameters.Add("OrderNumber", order.OrderNumber);
Command.Parameters.Add("Operation", order.Operation);
```

In the query are 3 parameters `:OrderNumber` twice and `:Operation` once so I added both to the parameter list. After all, you only have to assign a variable to a parameter once in the Oracle SQL Developer application.

Here's the tricky part. The reason why I got error `ORA-01008` was justified. I got **3** parameters and I only added **2** to the parameter list hence the error.

The piece of code below is not a working version of the query:

```
Command.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(REQHOURS), SUM(REQQUANTITY) / COUNT(*) 
    FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDERNUMBER = :OrderNumber AND 
    OPERATION = (SELECT MIN(OPERATION) FROM ORDERS 
    WHERE ORDERNUMBER = :OrderNumber AND OPERATION > :Operation)";
Command.Parameters.Add("OrderNumber", order.OrderNumber);
Command.Parameters.Add("OrderNumber", order.OrderNumber);
Command.Parameters.Add("Operation", order.Operation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify parameter name with `:`. I thing you just missed that because you mentioned you have already working queries :). So in your case:

```
Command.Parameters.Add(":OrderNumber", order.OrderNumber);
Command.Parameters.Add(":Operation", order.Operation);
```

Comment: Correct parameters are placeholders so they need to be defined in same way they are used, using the colon as a prefix

Comment: Not in my case. I have the same approuch for multiple functions and queries like I illustrated. Nowhere I have to use the colons and everything is working fine. Also, like I said in my question, when I remove the last AND the query is "working" but the DataReader is Null.

Comment: Have you tried? I guess not. In your case I think your `Operation > :Operation` internally become `SomeOperationCode > :Operation` and that results not all variables bind problem. Other thing you can do just rename parameter to OperationParameter or something...see what you get then

Comment: Just try to help instead of insinuating I don't try answers out. I tested what you posted in your answer but it does not work. I also already tested changing `:Operation` to something else before posting, but this doesn't work either. I have the feeling it has something to do with the subquery.